# Print ` on fisrt keystroke

Tags: keyboard

I have Ubuntu 20.04 + Cinnamon 4.

When I type an accentuated characters (`, ^) it is not immediately printed, instead, it waits for a second keystroke so that <kbd>`</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> = è.

The problem is that of stack site, I have to type two ` or `+space to make inline code.

How could I display ` on the first keystroke?

My system is in french, and I use an AZERTY keyboard (so ` is <kbd>altgr</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>)

Comment: are you using an AZERTY or QWERTY keyboard and what have you set up in Settings > Language and Region? Please [edit] your question, not add to the comment trail. It would seem that the first keypress is "latching" which is how I use FR accents on a UK keyboard with the `compose` key.

Comment: There is no version of Ubuntu 20.4 there is a version 20.04

Comment: *How could I display ` on the first keystroke?* You don't, unless you want to break the ability to write accentuated characters like you need everyday for French. What you're "complaining" about is the "dead keys" feature that is required for typing in any language that frequently needs those characters (French happens to be one of the languages that need it the most).

Comment: You can, however, add a second keyboard layout without "dead keys" and toggle to that one when you need and toggle back to the original for normal text.

Comment: The è character is already available on the standard AZERTY keyboard - see [this reference](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-type-french-accents-1372770) so it would seem that you have not set the correct keyboard layout in Settings > Language and Region > Input sources

Comment: @ChanganAuto the azerty keyboard already have a è and à key. And ì or ò do not exist in french, so I do not need them. The ^ dead key is usefull, but not the ` one

Comment: @24601 è is indeed on the keyboard (on the 7 key). This is why I don't need dead key for `

Comment: News to me, I don't use AZERTY :) Well, you already know what to do, what are your options and consequences...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I had the wrong layout. (Settings -> Keyboard -> layout)
I changed it from "Français (variante obsolète)" to "Français". In this new layout, ^ is a dead key but ` is not which solves the problem